# Having encoding problems in Aptana Studio

Tags: php, encoding, aptana

A few months ago, I was working on a PHP project in Aptana Studio. It was version 1.5 or something. Later I installed Aptana 2.0 and created a new project with the same files. Back then it was UTF-8 so I chose UTF-8 for the project's text file encoding.

When I make changes in any PHP file using Aptana, it gives the error:

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent...**

I know it's a problem related to encoding. What can I do?

---

by the way if it's any help i'm using `session_start` in my php code which causes this error. But i'm sure there's no error in my code because everything's ok in the unedited version of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, when you use unicode with `BOM` - Bytes Order Mark. Look up, if you don't have somewhere checked this option - it is default setting in Dreamweaver and it once gave headaches.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't an encoding related problem. It's likely that you have a space or something before your opening PHP tag, so HTTP headers and the first character of the body are being sent to the client before you call header().